# MaskedEditValidator baloon tooltip - AJAX Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tooltip, help-balloon

I'm using [MaskedEditValidator for validating Date](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx) input. I want to show balloon like tool tip instead of the normal message in red color which is creating alignment problems everywhere.

I have to stick to MaskedEditValidator as lot of implementation is already done around it.

AJAX Control ToolKit Version : 3.5.40412.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ValidatorCallout](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx) extender for that purpose:

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="YourMaskedEditValidator" runat="server"
    ControlExtender="YourMaskedEditExtender"
    ControlToValidate="YourMaskedTextBox" Display="None" />

<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="YourMaskedEditCallout" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="YourMaskedEditValidator" />
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very very much :)